# Excel VBA - List Box Value Not Stored

Tags: excel, vba

So I am currently working on Userforms in Excel to input and edit database of employees in my department.

Something like this:
[example of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1z7B.png)

Using Userform to input new data works fine. You just sets Cells value in active Sheet to correspond with Value Choosen in the Userform.

My problem appears when I try to edit old data. What I did is basically made a simple search system based on ID#. When I click the Edit button it will store all relevant info to Public Variable I stored in a module called "Var." All variable is stored as String.

```
Dim rowsearach as Long, Name As String, BranchRegion As String, BranchProvince As String, BranchCity As String, Phone As String

rowsearch = WorksheetFunction.match(Var.editid, Range("A:A"), 0)

Var.Name = Cells(rowsearch, 2).Value
Var.BranchRegion = Cells(rowsearch, 3).Value
Var.BranchProvince = Cells(rowsearch, 4).Value
Var.BranchCity = Cells(rowsearch, 5).Value
Var.Phone = Cells(rowsearch, 6).Value
```

Now, the storing of those value in the Public variable worked fine, I've tried to write all of them to empty Cells and it worked.

The next step is calling the edit userform (which is the same as userform I used for new data input) in which the content of the userform will be filled with those variables above stored in "Var" module.

**Name**            : Textbox

**Branch Region**   : Listbox, listbox item is updated during Userform initialization

**Branch Province** : Listbox, listbox item is updated on Branch Region listbox change (the Province shown depends on what Region is chosen)

**Branch City**     : Combo-box, combo-box item is updated on Branch Province listbox change (the City shown depends on what Province is chosen)

**Telephone**       : Textbox

My problem lies within getting the value of Branch Region. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize
With ListboxRegion
.Additem "West"
.Additem "Central"
.Additem "East"
.Value = Var.Region
End With
```

My problem is, on the Region section, while the userform seemingly able to import the value from Var.Region as follows (the region is set to Central in this example):[pictured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdH8g.png). In the picture you could see that while Central section is selected, when I finish the editing through a "Finish Button" in which:

```
Cells(rowid, 3).Value = ListboxRegion.Value
```

The value cells in Cells(rowid, 3) will be null/empty. I've tried code it to write the value of ListboxRegion to other cells before clicking "Finish Button", but it also returns empty.

**The problem, seemingly, is while Listbox has shown that the Region has been chosen, in actual the value is not stored in ListboxRegion.Value**

This is a problem because user might now want to edit the region at all and just edit the other entries, but if they do no re-click the correct Region again, when they finish, the Region part of the database will begone.

I have 0 idea whats wrong with my code or how I implement it.

Comment: Can you try hardcoding, e.g. `.Value = "Central"` and seeing if that works.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a simple typo. `Var.BranchRegion = Cells(rowsearch, 3).Value` is used while storing cell value to var, while `.Value = Var.Region` is used in `UserForm_Initialize`

Any way use `Debug.Print ListboxRegion.ListIndex` at the end of `UserForm_Initialize` and at the start of Finish Button Event to get some indication of what's going wrong.